# How to find the position of :before element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this animation taking place in which i need to change the color of the element in the centre when the small circle touches it, i thought i could find it using position() but since i am using a :before for animating the div the position values are not useful, Is there a way i could achieve this or any other way to find out when the small circle intersects the large one.

https://jsfiddle.net/pwqfh7ys/5/

```
html

<figure class="glob-wrapper">
    <div class="goos">
        <div class="goo"></div>
        <div class="goo"></div>
        <div class="goo"></div>
        <div class="goo"></div>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/hello.svg" class="hello"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="blobs">
        <div class="blob"></div>
    </div>
</figure>

css
```

Comment: `:before` is not part of the dom

Comment: @charlietfl fair enough but is there any other way i could get to my solution

Comment: Probably need to use a visualization library and not use `:before`

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify pseudo elements through JavaScript since they are not part of the DOM. Your best bet is to define another class in your CSS with the styles you require and then add that to the element. Since that doesn't seem to be possible from your question, perhaps you need to look at using a real DOM element instead of a pseudo one.

hope the below snippet might help, you can specify the content value you want via JS using the CSS attr() function.

Javascript

```
$('.blob').on('click', function () {
    //do something with the callback
    $(this).attr('data-before','anything'); //anything is the 'content' value
});
```

CSS:

```
.blob:before {
    content: attr(data-before); //value that that refers to CSS 'content'
    //css here
}
```

Comment: let's say that i do that, how do i find when the the two divs come in contact with each other i.e the small circle touching the center blob

Comment: Instead of adding :before add separate element / span or div

Comment: I am sorry if i wasn't clear, I am saying if i did create a separate element still how would i be able to find when the two elements touch each other